# Titanium: Have a touch event go through view

Tags: android, ios, titanium, titanium-mobile, titanium-alloy

I have an invisible view that is used as an area for a swipe (an area to open the menu swiping to the right). Problem is this view stops any click that would occur in elements that appear below it.
Any ideas on how to make this click/touch event go through without the complete removal of the swipe on my swipe area view? If I use the `touchEnabled` option it removes all the events.

Answer (score 0):

You could add the swipe event to the below elements and remove the invisible view completely.

Otherwise you could add the click to the invisible layer, calculate the y/x coordinates of the click, find out which element is at these coordinates and call the click element via code. But thats a lot of work and in my opinion not very reliable

Comment: Yeah, the first option is good but I'm not sure it will be viable since the elements below change a lot. I'll try something like your second option to see how feasible that would be.